# How should I use SWT get User's information from Azure ACS

Tags: azure, azure-acs

If I use Asp.net,I can add sts, and get user infomation from Claims.

But now I have a winform application, so I can't add STS reference in my project.
I need to let user login my app with Google account.

I can get SWT token in code behind.
But I don't know how to use this SWT get user account information.
Can any body help?
Thanks very much!

Comment: What you need is basic understanding of [Azure Authentication Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554309.aspx). Then you can go through the [code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554350.aspx). And after that, when something goes wrong, ask your question providing the exact code that you use with exact errors that you see.

Comment: I just want to get User's Live ID Name like claims in Winform app.

Comment: for Live ID, you can only get `NameIdentifier` claim. And that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Live ID, you can only get NameIdentifier claim.